# Ubit WIE7265 Wi-Fi PCI-e Card Driver install

Tags: networking, drivers, wireless, hardware, iwlwifi

This is my first time posting here and I'm pretty new to Linux/Ubuntu.  I am running Ubuntu 18.04 dual boot on a desktop computer.  I just got a new wifi card that is supposed to be compatible with Linux.  I have tried to use the "software & Updates" app under the "Additional Drivers" tab.  It recognizes the device as an Intel Corp. Wireless 7265 (dual band wireless-AC7265) but all the options are greyed out except "continue using a manually installed driver" but even that once selected I can't apply it.  I saw another post about this issue and it said to include the response to "dmesg | grep iwl"
this is what I get when i type that in:

~$ dmesg | grep iwl

```
[   15.357514] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: loaded firmware version 29.1044073957.0 op_mode iwlmvm
[   16.427459] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: Detected Intel(R) Dual Band Wireless AC 7265, REV=0x210
[   16.445140] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: base HW address: 34:02:86:2f:dd:93
[   16.504813] ieee80211 phy0: Selected rate control algorithm 'iwl-mvm-rs'
[   16.549604] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0 wlp1s0: renamed from wlan0
```

I have also tried to go to http://www.evisionde.com/prodetail.aspx?ProID=86 under the drivers tab and download both the linux 4.1 and linux 4.2 downloads with both saying "An error occurred while loading the archive".

I have hooked up an ethernet cable directly to the machine as I had read that it would get the driver automatically if I did that. It didn't.  I also tried the command "jockey-gtk" which didn't work either.

any help or advice on how to get this device working would be much appreciated.

thank you

Reefsider

Comment: HMMM well it seems to be working now lol.  I don't think I did anything but it is working now. I am on it right now.  The strange thing is inside the "software and updates" under the "additional drivers" tab it still says "This device is not working" and the options are still greyed out.  It is working though so unless I need to fix it, it's working well enough for me.

Comment: "This device is not working" It's a known issue with *iwlwifi*. You may safely ignore it.

Comment: Perfect, thank you for your reply :)